# How to set up ConEmu task for Selenium Grid

Tags: java, windows, selenium, 64-bit, conemu

I searched for this for some days now and haven't found a good resource.

I want to set up two tasks for the Selenium Grid to work "with just one click" in ConEmu. I added a task and set up a startup dir (where the Selenium Grid jar is located).

According to http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2 I need to start two instances of that jar with different parameters:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub
```

and

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

I wanted to have two tasks in ConEmu to start those two instances of Selenium. I tried to set up a task with

```
-new_console:d:D:\Downloads\Programming\Selenium

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub
```

This always leads me to following output in ConEmu

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar

Current directory:
C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu

Command to be executed:
"C:\Windows\system32\java.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub

ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

With the jar in the task it won't open the source path. When deleting the jar with parameters in the task, a new console opens and navigates to the correct folder.

I am totally lost here - how do I have to set up a task to run the Selenium grid automatically?

**Edit 1:** I added a screenshot from the current setup (-> http://tinyurl.com/q2mgkmx [as I do not have enough reputation, I altered the stackoverflow url with tinyurl; nothing to fear here ;) ]). I know this is wrong, as every entry in a new line opens a new tab in ConEmu. But I thought that the ">" parameter would mark the tab as "current tab" ...

**Edit 2:** Just for completeness: I do run the 64bit client on Windows 7.

Comment: From your question I'm not sure, but seems like you are trying to enter "-new_console" on the one line of the task, and your jar on **another** line? Why? You have not read info in the ConEmu's Tasks page?

Comment: Hi Maximus! Thank you for your fast answer. I read https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Settings#Tasks before posting this question, but that did not help me. Maybe you refer to another Tasks page? If so, it would be nice of you to share it with me. :)

Comment: Not a wiki. Just a Settings/tasks dialog. What there was written? ;-) One line - one tab.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question area (last passage). Maybe this is more understandable. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! *yay*

Screenshot of working hub and node: http://tinyurl.com/njkszq6 (Stackoverflow image)

I don't know if this might work better if set up in another way, but this should be fine for now. This is the setup I twiddled together from various sources:

```
>cmd /k color 4C & cd /d "D:\Downloads\Programming\Selenium" -cur_console:t:Hub & java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -role hub

>cmd /k RenameTab "Node" & color 2A & cd /d "D:\Downloads\Programming\Selenium" -cur_console:s1TVn & java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -role node
```

Screenshot of ConEmu setup: http://tinyurl.com/pnfyta5 (Stackoverflow image)

This opens both console windows on top and bottom of ConEmu. I added color to both windows. And they both start the respective hub and node of Selenium.

I still don't know why Maximus' line of code did not do the magic trick. But it was a really good hint on where to head to.

@Maximus: If you can shed some light into this, I would appreciate it greatly!

*Edit:* I added Maximus' hints to the setup.

Comment: There must be not space between `"` and `-`: `" -cur_console:t:Hub"`. Also, if you set "tab" title without space - quotation marks are not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub -new_console:d:D:\Downloads\Programming\Selenium
```

Comment: I added your line of code in the Commands window: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tUpI5.png 

Sadly it is still the same (ConEmu just won't change the directory...): http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv2S5.png

Comment: Hard to believe... There was a bug in prev build, try ConEmu 140227. It will show correct "startup directory" in error message. `-new_console:d:` must do the same thing, as you do with "`cd /d`". So, that is very strange that your jar was not found. If 140227 still fails, please show screenshots and run ProcessMonitor to catch "Process create" events.